# What is the difference between debug and release binaries in .NET?

Tags: .net, debugging

I am wondering what is the difference between debug and release binaries in .NET.

What does actually happen when I put `<compilation debug="true" />` instead of `<compilation debug="false" />` in a web config file for some web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/442448.aspx) may definitely answer your question.

> When **compilation debug=”false”/** is set, the WebResource.axd handler
>   will automatically set a long cache policy on resources retrieved via
>   it – so that the resource is only downloaded once to the client and
>   cached there forever (it will also be cached on any intermediate proxy
>   servers).  If you have Atlas installed for your application, it will
>   also automatically compress the content from the WebResources.axd
>   handler for you when **compilation debug=”false”/** is set – reducing
>   the size of any client-script javascript library or static resource
>   for you (and not requiring you to write any custom code or configure
>   anything within IIS to get it).

Answer (score -1):

When you run your web application in visual studio then you have two options 
1. Run in debug mode
2. Run without debug mode

If you set `debug="true"` then it will create dll(binaries) which will track debugging - Debug mode
If you set `debug="false"` then it will create dll(binaries) which will not track debugger points - Release mode